# Why am I getting error trying to mount a directory onto a file?

Tags: kubernetes

I have this prometheus deployment manifest file: to create prometheus deployment

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: prometheus
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "9090"
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        boardType: aarch64
      initContainers:
      - name: prometheus-data-permission-setup
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/chmod","-R","777", "/data"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: prometheus-data
          mountPath: /data
      containers:
      - name: prometheus
        image: rycus86/prometheus:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args:
          - '--storage.tsdb.path=/data'
          - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
        command:
        - /bin/prometheus
        ports:
        - name: web
          containerPort: 9090
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
          subPath: prometheus.yml
        - name: prometheus-data
          mountPath: /data
          readOnly: false
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "250m"
            ephemeral-storage: "4Gi"
          limits:
            memory: "200Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
            ephemeral-storage: "20Gi"
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: prometheus-config
      - name: prometheus-data
        hostPath:
          path: /data
          type: Directory
      serviceAccountName: prometheus
```

but this error that "trying to mount a directory onto a file "

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  30s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned monitoring/prometheus-b568c9967-tmdq7 to rockpro64
  Normal   Pulling    28s               kubelet            Pulling image "busybox"
  Normal   Pulled     26s               kubelet            Successfully pulled image "busybox" in 1.57966103s
  Normal   Created    26s               kubelet            Created container prometheus-data-permission-setup
  Normal   Started    25s               kubelet            Started container prometheus-data-permission-setup
  Warning  Failed     23s               kubelet            Error: failed to start container "prometheus": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/kubelet/pods/da8d1a99-a6d0-48f5-ad5e-cbc5db136145/volume-subpaths/config-volume/prometheus/0\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/32aead2ba4f70863e9cf643a1bad1fb0832eb43c217898bfe77cc67ab400d702/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/32aead2ba4f70863e9cf643a1bad1fb0832eb43c217898bfe77cc67ab400d702/merged/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
  Warning  Failed     23s               kubelet            Error: failed to start container "prometheus": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/kubelet/pods/da8d1a99-a6d0-48f5-ad5e-cbc5db136145/volume-subpaths/config-volume/prometheus/0\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9dcb8fa640d8fc93f56755f5daeb2a350c482f5f3f26faee03edb320d52f53ff/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9dcb8fa640d8fc93f56755f5daeb2a350c482f5f3f26faee03edb320d52f53ff/merged/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
  Warning  BackOff    22s               kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulled     7s (x3 over 24s)  kubelet            Container image "rycus86/prometheus:latest" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    7s (x3 over 24s)  kubelet            Created container prometheus
  Warning  Failed     6s                kubelet            Error: failed to start container "prometheus": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/kubelet/pods/da8d1a99-a6d0-48f5-ad5e-cbc5db136145/volume-subpaths/config-volume/prometheus/0\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5b263ca359000d143fd5f11fb26218ead46eabd1a1aeb39ce1a7b48302a2382c/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5b263ca359000d143fd5f11fb26218ead46eabd1a1aeb39ce1a7b48302a2382c/merged/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

I have prometheus-config configmap already setup.

```
# kubectl get cm -n monitoring
NAME                DATA   AGE
kube-root-ca.crt    1      35h
prometheus-config   1      41m
```

what might have gone wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

`volumeMount` based on `configMap` actually creates the files for the data keys. You don't need the filename in the `mountPath` or the `subPath`

```bash
$ cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
data:
  settings.conf: |
    test: config
    multi: line
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /etc/config/" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: test-config
EOF

$ kubectl logs dapi-test-pod
settings.conf
```

Ref:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

Comment: I have tried this already but it didn't help.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the correct example and reference.